# How to copy Druid data source data from prod server to QA server (like hive distcp action)

Tags: druid

I wanted to check if there is a way to copy Druid datasource data (segments) from one server to another. Our ask is to load new data to prod Druid (using SQL queries), and copy the same data to qa Druid server. We are using hive druid storage handler to load the data, and HDFS as deep storage.

I read Druid documentations, but did not find any useful information.

Comment: Any updates on this question? I wanted to do the same but can't seem to find any reliable way to do the same

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way to do this cleanly in druid.
If you really need this feature, please request this by creating a github ticket on : https://github.com/apache/druid/issues .

The workaround way is documented here : https://docs.imply.io/latest/migrate/#the-new-cluster-has-no-data-and-can-access-the-old-clusters-deep-storage

Full disclosure: I work for imply.